# Unable to copy new style file into Notepad++ under /snap

Tags: 18.04, snap, notepad-plus-plus

I installed Notepad++ in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS using Ubuntu Software. Notepad++ was installed under /snap.

I am trying to copy a new style file:

```
~/Desktop/Cobalt.xml
```

into the Notepad++ themes folder.

```
sudo cp Cobalt.xml /snap/notepad-plus-plus/238/winedata/Application\ Data/Notepad++/themes
```

I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/notepad-plus-plus/238/winedata/Application Data/Notepad++/themes/Cobalt.xml': Read-only file system
```

I was able to copy the file in folders `/snap` and `/snap/notepad-plus-plus`, but somehow from folder `/snap/notepad-plus-plus/238` it doesn't work anymore...

Any idea how to go around this ?

Comment: You can't create a folder in the snap itself as it is sandboxed and read-only.  However, you have a `~/snap/` folder where all the extra configuration and folders can be created.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I found the themes folder under ~/snap.